# Why do we call Yii2 static components method from thats child objects via arrow sign '->'?

Tags: php, yii2

In normal way, I know that we can call parent static method with `::` sign but it seems that in Yii2 Framework, we should call static components method via arrow sign (object operator).

I'd like to know how its possible?

For example, in

```
$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, 'function_name');
```

`on()` is an static method of `yii\base\component` but we call it with arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Component::on()` is not static:

> ```
> public function on($name, $handler, $data = null, $append = true)
> {
>     $this->ensureBehaviors();
>     if (strpos($name, '*') !== false) {
>         if ($append || empty($this->_eventWildcards[$name])) {
>             $this->_eventWildcards[$name][] = [$handler, $data];
>         } else {
>             array_unshift($this->_eventWildcards[$name], [$handler, $data]);
>         }
>         return;
>     }
>     if ($append || empty($this->_events[$name])) {
>         $this->_events[$name][] = [$handler, $data];
>     } else {
>         array_unshift($this->_events[$name], [$handler, $data]);
>     }
> }
> ```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/bc9a82ff80e0abc3ce1430310d2b9b1f70f18c62/framework/base/Component.php#L514

`Event::on()` is static:

> ```
> public static function on($class, $name, $handler, $data = null, $append = true)
> {
>     $class = ltrim($class, '\\');
>     if (strpos($class, '*') !== false || strpos($name, '*') !== false) {
>         if ($append || empty(self::$_eventWildcards[$name][$class])) {
>             self::$_eventWildcards[$name][$class][] = [$handler, $data];
>         } else {
>             array_unshift(self::$_eventWildcards[$name][$class], [$handler, $data]);
>         }
>         return;
>     }
>     if ($append || empty(self::$_events[$name][$class])) {
>         self::$_events[$name][$class][] = [$handler, $data];
>     } else {
>         array_unshift(self::$_events[$name][$class], [$handler, $data]);
>     }
> }
> ```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/bc9a82ff80e0abc3ce1430310d2b9b1f70f18c62/framework/base/Event.php#L103

But I've never seen that someone is using it in non-static way.

Comment: So why used :: sign to show "yii\base\Component::on()"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Did you expect something like `yii\base\Component->on()`?

Comment: `->`  is used only on object context, so using it with class name is confusing. `yii\base\Component::on()` is general convention in PHP, same for properties (`Someclass::$someNonStaticProperty`) and indicates only method/property identifier, without specifying access type. https://3v4l.org/I2rRb